# SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: laravel, controller, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a trouble about phpmyadmin of laravel
I want to update the data from the view on the db via controller but I get an error occurred

```
    // save all seats
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $param) {
        if ($key === '_token') continue;

        $data = explode('-', $key);

        $bs = new BookedSeat();
        $bs->booking_id = $booking->id;
        $bs->day_id = str_replace('c', '', $data[0]);
        $bs->table_id = str_replace('t', '', $data[1]);
        $bs->number = 0;
        $bs->status = 'requested';
        $bs->save();
    }
```

[its an error when i try update data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeAHo.png)

[its my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUVqG.png)

Comment: Please share your code for inserting data, and you need to insert the `day_id` foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
 // save all seats
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $param) {
    if ($key === '_token') continue;

    $data = explode('-', $key);

    $bs = new BookedSeat();
    $bs->booking_id = $booking->id;
    $day = DB::table('days')->where('name',$data[0])->get(); 
    $bs->day_id = $day->id;
    $bs->table_id = str_replace('t', '', $data[1]);
    $bs->number = 0;
    $bs->status = 'requested';
    $bs->save();
}
```

Comment: hi friend . id of book or id is book